# Approve member before payment

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, webform-civicrm, payment-processor

I need members to be approved by admin before they pay their membership. How do i do this?

I have setup membership levels and created the contribution page but I can not find any option for approve member before payment process. Do I need to create a free member and approve them? but then how do the system sends payment after I approve them? Do you know if there is anything that I can setup to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with the below steps -

1. Create a pay later contribution page for membership.
2. Let user register for membership using pay later. So Each Membership here would have a pending status.
3. Create a searchable custom field for Contribution Eg `Approved?` with `Yes No` Field values.
4. Set this to `yes` on editing contribution record for those you want to approve.

Completing the Pending Payment (If you're using above 4.7 version)-

1. Navigate to Administer -> CiviContribute -> CiviContribute Component Settings (civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/contribute?reset=1).
2. Check `Enable Deferred Revenue` option and set the `Default invoice payment page`. Record its page id(you can find it in `Manage Contribution Pages` where ids are shown for all of them).
3. From `Find Contribution` search for all whose Approved field is set to `yes`.
4. Select an action to send them an email mentioning the following URL.

   ```
   http://<site_name>/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id={page_id_from_step_2}&ccid={contribution_id_token}
   ```
5. Using this url, users will be able to complete their payment and `Pending` Membership would be updated to `New`.

Comment: WOW. Thank you so much! I will give it a try.